# create new column whilst calling on two data sets

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to have a new column created (pasting Mapped), if
1. `df1$col1` has `Connected`
2. `df1$col2 == df2$col2`

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(AConnect = paste('Mapped'[col1 == "Connected" & df1$col2 == df2$col2]))
```

> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

getting NA in the column.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df1` and `df2` has same number of rows you could do

```
df1$AConnect <- NA_character_
df1$AConnect[df1$col1 == "Connected" & df1$col2 == df2$col2] <- "Mapped"
```

Using `dplyr` that can be written as

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  mutate(AConnect = ifelse(col1 == "Connected" & col2 == df2$col2, "Mapped", NA))
```

This assigns `"Mapped"` where `col1 == "Connected"` and `col2 == df2$col2` otherwise `NA`.

Comment: seems to leave NA on the majority of them, however one is successfully mapped. Not sure if you have any other ideas?

```df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(AConnect = ifelse(col1 == "Connected" & col2 == df2$col2, "Mapped", NA))```

Comment: after testing the code separate, seems like calling on ``` col2 == df2$col2 ``` is where it is failing to look up a value 'xxx-xx-xxxx' that matches one in the other column's df

Comment: Solved - needed %in% as was matching within a column - not equaling that specific row

Comment: @HP. ohh..I see. It was difficult for me to guess since there was no data shared. I just followed your post where it mentioned `2. df1$col2 == df2$col2`

Answer (score 0):

Solved - needed %in% as was matching within a column - not equaling that specific row –

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(AConnect = ifelse(cl1 == "Connected" & col2 %in% df2$col2, "Mapped", NA))
```